# Why does the Nyquist frequency of FFT of even length dataset end up on negative side of spectrum?

Tags: signal-processing, fft

When computing the FFT of an even length dataset, you end up with an even number of frequency bins, and so it is not symmetric about zero. The additional frequency bin, which is at the Nyquist frequency, ends up going in the negative side of the double sided spectrum rather than the positive side - I would like to understand why this is the case, but haven't been able to find an answer.

I've tried Googling and looking elsewhere on Stack Overflow, for example: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/465242-fftshift-with-even-and-odd-number-of-data-points-scaling-the-positive-and-negative-frequency-axis

However nothing I have found has answered my question yet.

Comment: This is more of a DSP theory question than a programming question, so it is probably better suited to the DSP StackExchange site: https://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hi @PaulR Would you recommend deleting this post and asking again there?

Comment: It probably doesn't matter too much for this question, particularly if you already have the answer(s) that you're looking for, but for future reference if you have DSP theory questions you'll probably get better answers on dsp.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nyquist bin “wraps around” because the spectrum is periodic, so the +Fs/2 bin is the same as the -Fs/2 bin. You can also view the spectrum as being at all positive frequencies if you prefer, with the Nyquist bin in the middle at +Fs/2.

Answer (score 2):

Bin at Nyquist frequency is unique, it is neither positive or negative, its a margin, just like zero is between positive and negative numbers. Nyquist frequency does not have its counterpart.

Lets say we have N=8 FFT:

```
[0] -> DC
[1, 2, 3] -> positive f1, f2, f3
[4] -> Nyquist frequency
[5, 6, 7] -> negative f3, f2, f1
```